# Does guice MapBinder expose binding key for injection?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Suppose I have class Fruit

```
class Fruit extends FruitBase {
  @Inject Fruit(Type type) {...}   
}
```

FruitBase injects some stuff via method injection, so Fruit has to be injected through Guice as well.

Now I need in another class to inject a `Map<Type, Fruit>`. So I create a `MapBinder`. Easiest thing to do is to create a few subclasses of Fruit for each type:

```
class Orange extends Fruit {
  @Inject Orange() {
    super(Type.ORANGE);
  }
}

// and later
mapBinder.addBinding(Type.ORANGE).to(Orange.class);
```

But if I don't want to create a bunch of simple subclasses and instead have MapBinder inject the label I'm binding to (`Type.ORANGE`, `Type.APPLE`) into Fruit itself? So I would have:

```
mapBinder.addBinding(Type.ORANGE).to(Fruit.class);
mapBinder.addBinding(Type.APPLE).to(Fruit.class);
```

and then my injected Map will have two instances of Fruit: one with type ORANGE, and one with APPLE.

Is that possible?

I found one workaround here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-guice/m-m9LiVsgSM/pKVi2EIILCsJ

but `factories.get(type).create(type);` just kinda smells.

Answer (score 2):

You can use binding to pre created instances. Note, in this case the instances created not by injector **but** members of these instances will be injected anyway later.

```
mapBinder.addBinding(Type.ORANGE).toInstance(new Fruit(Type.ORANGE));
mapBinder.addBinding(Type.APPLE).toInstance(new Fruit(Type.APPLE));
```

But same instances will be shared between several injected maps, that can cause problems.

Comment: interesting, I'll have to check that!

Comment: There is a comprehensive example in the docs that more or less explains everything - http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html